# embed a terminal command in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, mac

I know this may be extravagant, but I was wondering if it was possible to embed a terminal command in a beamer pdf that can be launch by clicking on it. My idea is that during my presentation, I could just click on a button displayed on my slide to launch a program. This way, I don't have to quit the presentation and open a terminal window.

I'm using **mac OSX** and I need the view the pdf **with Adobe Reader**. Is there a way to do it without using php forwarding like in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22960/a-button-that-runs-an-external-program-from-a-beamer-pdf-presentation)?

### Edit:

I tried this code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{shell.command}
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "Hello, World!"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \href{run:shell.command}{here}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And Adobe Reader says it can't find an app to open the file. I also tried opening the file with Safari and it shows the script file, it doesn't run it. This is annoying because if I click on the `shell.command` file through the Finder, it simply runs it, as it should.

Comment: @Papiro The linked doesn't work in Evince at least, but mine does.

Comment: Although this is technically a duplicate, both of the solutions seem only to work on Windows. I would prefer to repopen this an get a solution on the record that works with Linux/OS X.

Comment: @AlanMunn Agreed -- I'm thinking there might be a difference in how  they each handle application calls.  Perhaps someone can test it within Evince on Linux, since that worked on Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doing this in combination with `listings` gives you a pretty nice solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,hyperref,listings}

\begin{filecontents*}{script.bat}
@echo off
echo "Hello, World!"
pause
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=csh,float,caption={A Windows batch file}]{script.bat}

Click \href{run:script.bat}{here} to run the script.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

This should also work with Beamer.

---

#### Edit

If you're working with a UNIX system, note that `bat` is Windows-only, since Windows doesn't use a 'real' shell.  With UNIX, give it a `.sh` extension (if you want to give it one at all).  You might also need to do a few more things:

- Make sure the file is executable: run `chmod +x myscript.sh`
- Give the file a shebang line:

`script.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "Oh, the wonderful possibilities of UNIX shells."
```

Please note that, as of now, this solution [may not always work on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125411/).

Note also that the handling of `run:` protocols can vary from viewer to viewer.
Some may not support it at all due to security risks, but it has been confirmed that Evince and Skim support it.

Comment: I just tried that and adobe reader pops up an error saying it can't find a program to run `shell.bat`.

Comment: @user2482876 Are you on Windows, or a UNIX variant (eg Mac)?  If you're using UNIX, rename `shell.bat` to `shell.sh`; Windows uses the `bat` extension to indicate BATch scripts, where UNIX variants usually use `sh` to indicate SHell scripts. (Technically, the [Bourne shell](http://docs.jach.hawaii.edu/JAC/JACUN/008.0/node42.html).)

Comment: ah! yes i'm on OSX. It makes way more sense!

Comment: I tried again using `.sh` this time and it gave me the same error. Should I make an actual shell script file and use `run:./shell.sh` ?

Comment: The `filecontents*` environment should be writing it... check the directory to make sure it exists and, probably more importantly, ensure that it is executable.  (`chmod +x shell.sh`)

Comment: the `shell.sh` file is created and I made it executable, but adobe reader still says it can't find a program to open it.

Comment: Are `@echo off` and `pause` commands for the latex compiler?

Comment: `@echo off` and `pause` are batch commands; neither are truly necessary, it just makes the shell look nicer. Hmm. I'll edit my answer for you, since this is particular to UNIX stuffs.  If you take a look at the linked question though, I'm not sure if Reader allows this.

Comment: I also tried with `Preview` (the mac pdf viewer) without more luck.

Comment: Try that -- particularly the shebang line.

Comment: I tried it without luck. I also tried to make it more like an executable, by changing `.sh` to `.command` and giving it the permissions and that didn't do it either.

Comment: @user2482876: It works with Skim, though (if the x bit is set). Apparently, every PDF viewer implements the `run:` handler differently on OS X :-(

Comment: @Daniel: Yeah, after some research I realized that too. I'll try skim. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel nice observation; I've noted the disparity in the answer.

Comment: I am getting `The application can’t be opened.`error

Comment: @alper you are unlikely to get help from a ten-year-old question; please ask a new one (and link to this old question in your new post) :-)

Comment: Actually it works in  Skim pdf viewer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok here's how to do it on **OSX**. Big thanks to everybody, especially to **Sean Allred** and Daniel.

### Step 1

Your `.tex` file should follow this structure:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{shell.command}
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "This finally works!"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \href{run:shell.command}{here}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Using `.command` instead of `.sh` will make the script executable by the system.

### Step 2

Go in terminal, `cd` into the directory and give the script the permission to run with:

```
chmod +x shell.command
```

### Step 3

Use **Skim** to read the `.pdf` file because different readers seem to interpret differently the `run:` command.

Comment: I should note that Skim probably isn't the only one that works, but it has (obviously) been confirmed to do so.  Evince works in Windows, so it will likely also work on OSX (and other *nix/bsd flavors).  As a side note, isn't this basically the content in an existing answer?

Comment: @SeanAllred It seems that the crucial distinction is that the file must have the `.command` or the `.tool` extension.  See [What is the difference between .command, .tool, and .sh file extensions?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24262)

Comment: @AlanMunn I still don't believe that should make a difference, but I'll take your word for it until I can play with it some myself.  It's weird that the extension would matter, since the default on OSX is to run `sh` extensions in Terminal with `bash`.  (At least, it's been set as the default so long on my computer that I don't remember setting it. ;-) I'll have to see.)

Comment: @SeanAllred The issue is that since the `run:` command interfaces with the GUI part of the OS (not the underlying BSD part), it needs to execute a file that the GUI part of the OS understands, and for OS X this is files named `.command` or `.tool`, i.e. double clickable shell scripts.  A regular `.sh` file is only executable from within the Terminal, but not by double clicking in the Finder, and `run:` behaves as if it's in the Finder.

Comment: I did try using `.sh` and it opened the file in a text editor (Xcode by default on my computer).

Comment: Just to be clear for others who might encounter this answer, the `filecontents` part of the answer is not required; the `.command` file simply needs to be in the same folder as the `.pdf` file, and can be created in any way.

Comment: Gotcha.  I must have changed it on mine, then.

Comment: Only downside, it still doesn't work with **Adobe Reader**, which I need to use because of animations in my beamer presentation.