# filecontents* cannot write to file in Windows

Tags: external-files, filecontents

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,hyperref,listings}

\begin{filecontents*}{script.bat}
@echo off
echo "Hello, World!"
pause
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=csh,float,caption={A Windows batch file}]{script.bat}

Click \href{run:script.bat}{here} to run the script.
\end{document}
```

I always receive the error

> ```
> ERROR: I can't write on file `script.bat'.
>
> --- TeX said ---
> <to be read again> 
>                    \relax 
> l.4 \begin{filecontents*}{script.bat}
> ```

In interactive mode (`pdflatex test`), this error continues until a filename is given which does not have that 'bat' extension.  What's going on here?

Comment: I have no problem on my system.

Comment: no problem here on a linux system.

Comment: No problem on my Mac.

Comment: Same problem with system file extensions like `.com`, `.dll`, etc too in Windows!

Comment: This is because windows (at least the latest versions) block running .bat and certain other files due to the security risks. You will see it works fine if you change `.bat` to `.txt`. I'm not sure you can make this possible without severely compromising the security of your windows machine.

Comment: Yes, we can do one thing just as a workaround. If you have CygWin installed, give `\begin{filecontents*}{script.txt}` and after `\end{filecontents*}`, in next line give `\immediate\write18{mv script.txt script.bat}`. This will work. Of course, you need to enable `--shell-escape`. I tested and this works.

Comment: Working on a latex "virus"? I know you loose a little bit and it won't fix your problem, but why not just simply have a static batch file, where is the advantage in generating it from tex?

Comment: @ted It is common practice here on TeX.SX to include auxiliary files within a single source, so that the solution is as portable as possible.  When answering a question, I ran into this problem the *second* time I ran it.  (The first time it worked wonderfully.)  Writing a TeX virus would be far more... sneaky ;)

Comment: @barbarabeeton,Jubobs as Mythio has pointed out, it does appear to be Windows-specific.  I've also never had a problem on my *nix installations.

Comment: @JagathAR Dirty trick, and not in the spirit of the motive for `filecontents` ;-)  (I also don't think Cygwin is a requirement; the appropriate DOS command is `REN` or `RENAME`.)

Comment: @SeanAllred: I Know that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows, you will generally encounter this error due to security reason. To get rid of such error you need to do follow this:

Set the value `openout_any = r` in `texmf.cnf`. Three options are available here, **any (a), restricted (r)** and **paranoid (p)**.

```
% Allow TeX \openin, \openout, or \input on filenames starting with `.'
% (e.g., .rhosts) or outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening "dotfiles".
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

**Note:** As per the suggestion from **@egreg**, I changed the option from **openout_any = a** to **openout_any = r**, which also works successfully in Windows.

Comment: I don't think this is good advice; allowing `openout_any=a` opens big security problems. And it probably wouldn't solve the problem, because it's the OS that prohibits writing files with `.bat` extension, it seems.

Comment: I know @egreg. But it is one of the solution to the question. I tried this in Windows machine and it worked!

Comment: @egreg: It's not the os, it has to be the latex implementation. After all you can create and edit bat files with other editors. But I agree removing the restictions is bad advice. I think the rename approach sounds rather good (can one test from inside tex if it is running on windows), since running a tex file with shell escapes makes it obvious that one runs into a security risk. However I don't know which security risk is higher letting latex execute shell commands, or generating a bat that first has to be launched by the user (possibly from the pdf as in the example).

Comment: @ted It might be MiKTeX's implementation, but I didn't find any mention.

Comment: What is odd here is that doesn't seem to be documented, but certainly does seem to be deliberate!