How to write Python file from LaTeX document (Windows)
The following code works on Linux and MacOS:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}[force]{world.pl}
print("Hello World")
\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting[language=Perl]{world.pl}

\begin{filecontents*}[force]{world.py}
print("Hello World")
\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{world.py}
\end{document}

But with Windows (11) and TexLive (2024), I got the following error:
world.py: Forbidden to open for writing
! I can't write on file `world.py'.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.12 \begin{filecontents*}[force]{world.py}

Creating the Perl script works but not creating the Python script.
How to solve this problem?

Old question but very similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125411/82917

Depends also where you compiling from. Try running the script through command prompt as Administrator. If you use an editor to compile is pretty much the same.

@campa Thanks. My question can be closed as duplicate.
