# Link to .mov file not working using href in OSX and beamer

Tags: beamer, links

I'm trying to embed a link to a `.mov` file in a `beamer` presentation. As I've read in similar posts I used the following code:

For an image:

```
href{run: ./graficas/quantumbeating.mov}{
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]
{./graficas/video1.png}}\\
```

For text link:

```
\href{run: ./graficas/quantumbeating.mov}{video}
```

I also tried with:

```
\href{run:/usr/bin/vlc -fs ./graficas/quantumbeating.mov}{video}
```

None of these alternatives actually worked (the code compiles, but nothing happens when the link is pressed). I would like Quicktime or VLC to open when the link is hit.

Comment: You are missing a `\ ` in your first line in front of `href`. The first two examples don't have a command for the media player, you want to use. Does you vlc exist in `/usr/bin/vlc`? If yes, please give us a complete minimal working example to try fixing your problem.

Comment: What happens if you type `/usr/bin/vlc -fs ./graficas/quantumbeating.mov` into a command line?

Comment: In Acrobat Reader, the first solution works.

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

Based on the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125443/36296 you could - rather than play the video directly - open a shell script, which plays the video

```
\begin{filecontents*}{shell.command}
#!/usr/bin/env sh
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -f ~/Desktop/test.mov
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \href{run:shell.command}{here}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

the run: protocol handling depends on the viewer.
you could give a try at [Présentation.app](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation).
the page describes how to integrate videos in the slides using this macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\pdfmovie}[4]{\href{run:#1}{\framebox{\parbox[c][#3][c]{#2}{\center #4}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\pdfmovie{720p25_pedestrian.mov}{6cm}{4cm}{H.264 avi}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

it will add the first frame of the macro on the slide and play the video fullscreen when clicked.

Comment: It's definitely better to post full examples instead of fragments of code. Please elaborate on your solution

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please include more details to your answer? For instance, providing a solution as [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304) would be great.

Comment: changed example to MWE