# Start an external program from Beamer' presentation using PREVIEW Mac

Tags: beamer, texshop

I would like to be able to START or RUN an external program from within the presentation by clicking a link, using PREVIEW.

Is this possible using Beamer package ? I am using Mac OS X Snow Leopard with Preview.

for example : a link to an image in my drive that allow me to start it in preview app ...

I found it but only works from within TEXSHOP not PREVIEW, here is an example :

```
\href[]{file:///Users/Alji/seg.jpg}{run}
```

Comment: Related: [A button that runs an external program from a Beamer PDF presentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22960/a-button-that-runs-an-external-program-from-a-beamer-pdf-presentation)

Comment: I saw that post ... it does not answer my question but thank you any way ...

Comment: If the answer to the linked question doesn't help you, could you tell us more about your problem? Otherwise, your question is likely to get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: what I can add is that : I want a clickable link in PREVIEW .... I will add it to the post.

Comment: @ALJIMohamed: Some external interactions in PDF documents are dependent on the viewer you use. While most things are available in Adobe, other viewers tend to lack or ignore some specifications. This might very well be the case here (where you mention it works from within TeXshop, but not in Preview).