# Start Matlab code directly from Latex

Tags: beamer, code, matlab

I'm using the documentclass beamer to make a presentation.
Is there a way to start Matlab code directly from Latex? A button that I can press so that the Matlab code starts to run automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have too much hair and you want to loose them or paint them gray? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: may be you can do it by executing shell script from Latex? check bashful package. Put the matlab command there to run Matlab.

Comment: similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22960/a-button-that-runs-an-external-program-from-a-beamer-pdf-presentation